# SQL Server 2012 SSIS: Is there a way copy packages/connections/objects/etc. from old SSIS solution to new solution that won't create GUID conflicts?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an existing SQL Server 2012 SSIS solution, deployed and pulling data from an external (Oracle) server each day. I need to copy all connections / variables / packages from that solution and put it in a new solution I'm writing.

Once I copy it to the new solution, I will rename each package and adjust the queries in the data flow source pull object; then save, build, deploy as a whole new solution. The old one will not change or go away. I'm just trying to use the project/solution itself as a template, pulling variable/logging/metadata that's not as easily by opening a package.

Is this doable? I don't see many answers doing a quick Google search. Forgive me if this is a duplicate question, unclear or easier than it appears.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio click on your project and select the "Add existing package" from the context menu. This makes a copy of the dtsx file, and leaves the original intact. Then you can make edits to your new copy.

[image: SSIS contect menu]

Comment: I was looking for a way to copy an entire project but this works as well for the package bits.